# What am I doing wrong here?

Tags: mysql, join

I am trying to fetch User's Role Name by traversing through multiple tables in MySql. If I pull User.Id everything works but right after I add one more level for UserRole.Name it throws an error.

### Error

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON Opportunity.AccountId = Account.Id' at line 2
```

### DB Tables

```
Opportunity has AccountId as column.
Account has UserId  as column.
User has UserRoleId as column.
UserRole has Name as column.
```

### Query

```
SELECT UserRole.Name FROM Opportunity
LEFT JOIN Account JOIN User JOIN UserRole ON User.UserRoleId = UserRole.Id ON Account.UserId = User.Id ON Opportunity.AccountId = Account.Id LIMIT 1\G
```

Comment: Show us the `SHOW CREATE TABLE name;` output, for all 4 tables.

Comment: Unfortunately the result of this query is not provided to me. I know you are trying to get structure of table. Can you share your thoughts on if there I am doing anything wrong in terms of syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax is valid SQL. I'm formatting a bit differently and adding parentheses to show how it is / should be parsed:

```
SELECT UserRole.Name 
FROM 
    Opportunity
  LEFT JOIN 
    (   Account 
      JOIN 
        (   User 
          JOIN 
            UserRole 
          ON 
            User.UserRoleId = UserRole.Id
        ) 
      ON 
        Account.UserId = User.Id 
    )
  ON 
    Opportunity.AccountId = Account.Id
```

It seems that the version of MySQL you use does not parse this correctly when the internal joins are `INNER` ones. If they were all `LEFT` joins, it wouldn't have a problem.

There are 2 solutions:

A) Use the above, with the parentheses.

B) Rewrite, changing the order of the joins, so the they not nested. You'll have to replace the `LEFT` to a `RIGHT` join but you don't need parentheses:

```
SELECT UserRole.Name 
FROM 
            User 
          JOIN 
            UserRole 
          ON 
            User.UserRoleId = UserRole.Id
      JOIN              
        Account 
      ON 
        Account.UserId = User.Id 
  RIGHT JOIN 
    Opportunity
  ON 
    Opportunity.AccountId = Account.Id
```